# error python 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python

Hi im trying to run this code and i get this error. Anybody can help?

```
mydict = {"name":"Peter", "age":29, "hasaandroid":True}
mydict["location"] = "NewZealand"
print(mydict)

sentence = 'Hello my name is {} and i am {} years old. I live in    {}.'.format(mydict('name'), mydict('age'), mydict('location'))
```

This last code gives me an error like this

```
> TypeError Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12864/3967542089.py in <module>
> ----> 1 sentence = 'Hello my name is {} and i am {} years old. I live in {}.'.format(mydict('name'), mydict('age'), mydict('location'))
> 
> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: dict('name') should be dict['name']

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, since a `dict` is correctly indexed on a previous line.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to use square brackets, instead of parenthesis.

```
sentence = 'Hello my name is {} and i am {} years old. I live in    {}.'.format(mydict['name'], mydict['age'], mydict['location'])
```

Parenthesis `(` and `)` are used to call an object, like invoking it as a function. Instead, use `[` and `]` to index a variable.

Answer (score 0):

For building these kinds of strings, you're best off using an f-string, rather than using `.format()`. Also note that you need to use square brackets `[]` to index into the dictionary, rather than using parentheses `()`:

```py
f'Hello my name is {mydict["name"]} and i am {mydict["age"]} years old. I live in {mydict["location"]}.'
```

This outputs:

```
Hello my name is Peter and i am 29 years old. I live in NewZealand.
```

Comment: While this is a valid point, it's not the actual problem with the original question.